# Benchmark analysis and display results of analysis AND benchmark?

Tags: r, benchmarking

Probably, I just missed a parameter... but, maybe someone can point me to it: How can run analysis in R benchmark it and still store the result back somewhere?. I know R functions can only return one single object, but I could either make use of a list here or paste the benchmark results and store the analysis in the function's return value.

But, is there any way to evaluate benchmark (or `system.time`) and analysis without running it twice like this?:

```
require(rbenchmark)
bmark <- function(x){
    res <- list()
    res[[1]] <- benchmark(x^6)
    res[[2]] <- x^6
    res
}
```

EDIT: I am sorry I caused some confusion about what I really want to do. Maybe the use case makes it clearer: I don't have a typical benchmark situation where I want to check whether my custom function is faster than some other function. It's rather that I run the same thing with different data on different machines. I don't need this in a test environment, but in production – I just want to let users of a script know how long it took. If that's an hour or more people can plan their lunch break :) .

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example using two functions. The first one uses `plyr` and the second uses `data.table`.

```
# dummy data
require(plyr)
require(data.table)
set.seed(45)
x1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1e6), grp = sample(letters[1:26], 1e6, replace=T))
x1.dt <- data.table(x1, key="grp")
# function that uses plyr   
DF.FUN <- function(x) {
    ddply(x1, .(grp), summarise, m.x = mean(x))
}

# function that uses data.table
DT.FUN <- function(x) {
    x1.dt[, list(m.x=mean(x)),by=grp]
}

require(rbenchmark)
> benchmark( s1 <- DF.FUN(), s2 <- DT.FUN(), order="elapsed", replications=2)

#             test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 2 s2 <- DT.FUN()            2   0.036    1.000     0.031    0.006          0         0
# 1 s1 <- DF.FUN()            2   0.527   14.639     0.363    0.163          0         0
```

Now, `s1` and `s2` contain the results from each function, and the benchmarked results will be displayed on screen.

```
# > head(s1)
#   grp           m.x
# 1   a  0.0069312201
# 2   b -0.0002422315
# 3   c -0.0129449586
# 4   d -0.0036275338
# 5   e  0.0013438022
# 6   f -0.0015428427

# > head(s2)
#    grp           m.x
# 1:   a  0.0069312201
# 2:   b -0.0002422315
# 3:   c -0.0129449586
# 4:   d -0.0036275338
# 5:   e  0.0013438022
# 6:   f -0.0015428427
```

Is this what you were after?

Comment: I test and data.table is 20 times faster :) +1 even if we have to install 2 packages:)

Answer (score 1):

I read the question a bit differently than Arun. This would be the answer to what I thought was being asked:

```
 > bres <- bmark(2)
> bres
[[1]]
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  x^6          100   0.001        1     0.001    0.001          0         0

[[2]]
[1] 64
```

The bmark function is returning a result with the default 100 replications. It you wanted to annotate the results you could use paste() and if you wanted to add a parameter for number of reps:

```
bmark2 <- function(x, reps=100){
    res <- list()
    res[[1]] <- benchmark(x^6, replications=reps)
    res[[2]] <- paste(reps, " replications of ", x, "to the 6th in", res[[1]]$elapsed)
    res
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer +1, indeed that is very close and helps, just that I don't need no replications here. Edited my question to (hopefully) make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of what StackOverflow thinks about answering old questions, but it seems like nobody actually answered after your edit. So here goes:

To time a process in R you can use two methods.
The first one uses `system.time(expression)` and gives you how much time it took to evaluate the expression within the brackets.
If this is not practical in your case you can get system time with `Sys.time()` before the operation and after the operation and subtract the two.

If this finally answers your question please accept the solution :)